# Парсер для сайта

Tags: php, парсер

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос: есть сайт, на котором имеется обычный поиск по сайту. Необходимо написать парсер, который открывает главную страницу этого сайта, берет из моей базы значение, вставляет его в поиск по тому сайту и собирает результат. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать этот самый поиск?

Comment: ссылку на сайт ?

Comment: Предлагаю реализовать программно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего поиск по сайту реализован стандартно - через GET запрос. Т.е можно сформировать ссылку типа `www.example.com/?s=*поисковый_запрос*` и далее через 
`file_get_contents` получить данные с сайта и уже после их разгребать.

Но это довольно топорный способ, если задача сложнее то советую посмотреть в сторону библиотек для PHP [Пост на хабре](https://tproger.ru/digest/parse-html-via-php/). и, если нужно, то познакомиться с [PhantomJS.](http://phantomjs.org/)